# Ajax POST success, but sql query not running

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, post

I have an ajax jQuery `post` that works. Or atleast, I think it does(I get the success message and see the POST data in browser) but the SQL query to update the database isn't working.

-----------------Function with the POST request -----------------------

```
var  examenid=examenid;
var checked=checked;

$.ajax
({
  type:'post',
   url:'updatecheckbox.php',
   data:{examenid: examenid,
         checked: checked
      },
  success:function(msg)
  {
      //if i set a message here, the message is displayed.
  }
```

---

-------------------updatecheckbox.php file -------------------------

```
 <?php
        // set defaults 
        $checkDigitaal;
        $checked = true;
        $examenid = '0';

        //open connection to database
        $link = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","","sprint");
        if (!$link) 
        {
        echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
            exit;
        }

    //check if the POST value is set
           if(isset($_POST['examenid'])){ $examenid = $_POST['examenid'];}
           if(isset($_POST['checked'])) {$checked = $_POST['checked'];}

        if($checked){$checkDigitaal = 0;}
        else{$checkDigitaal = 1;}

        //update query database
        $query="update examen set digitaal='$checkDigitaal' where examenid='$examenid'";  //your query

        if ($result = $link->query($query)) 
        {
                /* free result set */
            $result->free();
        }   

        mysqli_close($link);
 ?>
```

I expect that the update query runs and sets digital to 0 or 1 in the database. But right now nothing happens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what i do is echo json_encode("something to check like $checked"). to see what is actually happening and then in the ajax I console.log(msg) in the success.

Comment: the obligatory `"Your sql code is vulnerable to SQL injection"` warning should be stated. Use a `prepared statement` rather than embedding user supplied data in your sql.

Comment: As @RamRaider said you should not use this code in real life.
You can check if the SQL-update updates the database:
 if ($result = $link->query($query)) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($link);
}

Comment: Thanks for the warning RamRaider "Your sql code is vulnerable to SQL injection". I know it is and will change this.

Comment: What does the request return ? try maybe dumping some variable  in your php code and see what does the request return. Or maybe consider using debuger.

Comment: Added @nologin code to 'debug'  echo "Record updated successfully $checkDigitaal $examenid"    I got the message succesfull 0 0 so the variables are not being set ( and ofc this is the reason i don't see an update in the database)

Comment: in  chrome -> f12 -> network tab. i see form data $checked and examenid filled in. But in the updatecheckbox.php file the post data is not being set.

Comment: Solved, problem was the POST data that was wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code does not return / echo any value back to the ajax callback so the `success` function is being duped perhaps - use the logic of operation results in PHP to determine what is sent back.

An example of how you might implement `stored procedures` below with a response message for the ajax callback...untested

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'updatecheckbox.php',
    data:{
        examenid: examenid,
        checked: checked
    },
    success:function(msg){
        //if i set a message here, the message is displayed.
        console.info(msg)
    },
    error:function(err){
        console.warn(err);
    }
});



<?php

        $result = false;
        $checked = true;


        $link = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","","sprint");
        $examenid = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'examenid', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
        $checked = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'checked', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

        $checkDigitaal = $checked==1 ? 1 : 0;



        $sql='update `examen` set digitaal=? where examenid=?';
        $stmt=$link->prepare( $sql );

        if( $stmt && $examenid ){
            $stmt->bind_param( 'ii', $checkDigitaal, $examenid );
            $result = $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();
        }

        $link->close();

        /* send appropriate message based upon query result */
        exit( $result ? 'happy' : 'sad' );
?>
```

Comment: use return instead of exit

Comment: `return` is used from with a function whereas `exit` generally is used to terminate operations at that point

Comment: exit is IMHO for returning a status code (-1, 1) about operation-success and breaks the scripts running process. Didn't know that it "returns :)" strings too.
I do not develop without functions ;)

Comment: From the PHP manual: `exit — Output a message and terminate the current script`

Answer (score -1):

I have modified few lines of the code, please check whether this works or not

-----------------Function with the POST request -----------------------

```
var  examenid=examenid;
var checked=checked;

$.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'updatecheckbox.php',
        data:{"examenid": examenid, "checked": checked},
         success:function(msg){
          //if i set a message here, the message is displayed.     
     });
```

-------------------updatecheckbox.php file -------------------------

```
<?php
        // set defaults 
        $checkDigitaal;
        $checked = true;
        $examenid = 0;

        //open connection to database
        $link = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","","sprint");
        if (!$link) 
        {
        echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
            exit;
        }

    //check if the POST value is set
           if(isset($_POST['examenid'])){ $examenid = $_POST['examenid'];}
           if(isset($_POST['checked'])) {$checked = $_POST['checked'];}

        if($checked){$checkDigitaal = 0;}
        else{$checkDigitaal = 1;}

        //update query database
        $query="update examen set digitaal=$checkDigitaal where examenid=$examenid";  //your query

        if ($result = $link->query($query)) 
        {
                /* free result set */
            $result->free();
        }   

        mysqli_close($link);
 ?>
```

Comment: if digitaal and examenid are numbers you are right. Perhaps this hint is more a comment than an answer?

Comment: Due to my point I am not allowed to comment, so I can only help through comment

Comment: To give you constructive feedback: - I'm missing an explanation or sentence what your change is about (-> wrong type in sql statement).
- Do not copy/paste the whole code. The updated line is enough and the answer is more readable (shorter).